# How to find the relationship between the quaternion rate and angular velocity?

Tags: quaternions, rigid-transformation, robotics

I'm trying to find a solid proof of the relationship between the quaternion rate and angular velocity, but I keep running into the same problem.

#### Theorem:

If frame $B$ is rotating in frame $A$ at a constant angular velocity, then the rate of change of the quaternion is given by
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{\dot{q}} = \frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
      \boldsymbol\omega\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \otimes \mathrm{q}
  \end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol\omega\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is the angular velocity of frame $B$ in $A$.

#### Proof:

I'm mostly skipping through [this proof](https://www.ashwinnarayan.com/post/how-to-integrate-quaternions/).

A unit quaternion $\mathrm{q}$ describes a rotation of a vector via
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}'\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    = \mathrm{q} \otimes
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{v} \\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \otimes \mathrm{q}^*
  \end{equation}
where $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v}'$ is that vector described in a basis $A$ and $B$ respectively.
Let $\boldsymbol\omega$ be the angular velocity of reference frame $B$ in $A$. Then by the Transport Theorem, the derivative in basis $A$ is
\begin{equation}
    \frac{d}{dt} \mathbf{v}' = \frac{d}{dt} \mathbf{v} + \boldsymbol\omega \times \mathbf{v}'
  \end{equation}
Affix $\mathbf{v}$ in $A$ (i.e. $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{v}=0$).
Using that and expanding the derivative of $\mathbf{v}'$ gives
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{\dot{q}} \otimes
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{v} \\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \otimes \mathrm{q}^* + \mathrm{q} \otimes
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{v} \\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \otimes \mathrm{\dot{q}^*} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \boldsymbol\omega\times\mathbf{v}' \\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation}
Or in terms of $\mathbf{v}'$
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{\dot{q}}\otimes\mathrm{q^*}\otimes
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}'\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    +
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}'\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \otimes \mathrm{q} \otimes \mathrm{\dot{q}^*} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \boldsymbol\omega\times\mathbf{v}' \\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation}
Since the conjugate is the inverse of the quaternion
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{q}\otimes\mathrm{q^*} = 1 \implies
    \mathrm{\dot{q}} \otimes\mathrm{q^*}+\mathrm{q}\otimes\mathrm{\dot{q}^*} = 0 \implies
    \left(\mathrm{\dot{q}}\otimes\mathrm{q}^*\right)^*=-\mathrm{\dot{q}}\otimes \mathrm{q^*}
  \end{equation}
which implies that $\mathrm{\dot{q}}\otimes\mathrm{q}^*$ is a pure quaternion (For a quaternion $\mathrm{p}$, $-\mathrm{p}=\mathrm{p^*}$ is only true for a quaternion with a zero scalar part). Let $(\mathbf{u}, 0) = \mathrm{\dot{q}}\otimes\mathrm{q}^*=-\mathrm{q}\otimes\mathrm{\dot{q}^*}$, then
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{u} \\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \otimes
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}'\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    -
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}'\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \otimes
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{u}\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \boldsymbol\omega\times\mathbf{v}'\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation}
The left-hand side is the quaternion commutator. Expanded it becomes
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{u} \\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \otimes
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}'\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    -
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}'\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \otimes
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{u}\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}'-\mathbf{v}'\times\mathbf{u} \\
      \mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}'-\mathbf{v}'\cdot\mathbf{u}
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      2\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}'\\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation}
The vector part of the equation then becomes
\begin{equation}
    2\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}' = \boldsymbol\omega\times\mathbf{v}'
  \end{equation}
which only implies that $(2\mathbf{u}-\boldsymbol\omega)\times\mathbf{v}' = \mathbf{0}$.
The relationship $2\mathbf{u}=\boldsymbol\omega$ is true only if $2\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}'=\boldsymbol\omega\cdot\mathbf{v}'$.
If the relationship is true then
\begin{equation}
    2\mathrm{\dot{q}}\otimes\mathrm{q^*} =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \boldsymbol\omega \\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
  \end{equation}
Or re-arranging
\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{\dot{q}} = \frac{1}{2}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      \boldsymbol\omega \\
      0
    \end{pmatrix}
    \otimes \mathrm{q}
  \end{equation}

#### Problem:

The problem is solving the $(2\mathbf{u}-\boldsymbol\omega)\times\mathbf{v}'=\mathbf{0}$ bit. First define $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v}'$ so that they lie in a plane orthogonal to the axis of rotation. Then $\boldsymbol\omega\cdot\mathbf{v}'=0$ and you only have to prove that $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}'=0$: that $\mathbf{u}$ is also perpendicular with $\mathbf{v}'$. This [proof](https://www.ashwinnarayan.com/post/how-to-integrate-quaternions/) states that since the two quaternions are pure quaternions, their commutator is equal to their cross product is equal to their quaternion product. In other words
\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    2\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}'\\
    0
  \end{pmatrix}
  = 2
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf{u} \\
    0
  \end{pmatrix}
  \otimes
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf{v}' \\
    0
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
However this is only true if their dot product is zero: if $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}'=0$. I think I'm missing something in this [proof](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.2889.pdf). In section 1.5.1 (paraphrasing in my notation) they state that $|\mathbf{\dot{v}}'|=|2\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}|$ implies $\mathbf{u}\perp\mathbf{v}$, but how'd they get the norm relation? They reference the norm preserving property of the quaternion product $|\mathrm{p}\otimes\mathrm{q}|=|\mathrm{p}||\mathrm{q}|$, but I don't see where they're taking the quaternion product, just the cross product. And the cross product only preserves the norm if...$\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}'$ are perpendicular.

So how can I show that the "vector" $\mathrm{\dot{q}}\otimes\mathrm{q^*}$ points in the axis of rotation?